# sails js production mode does not display minified assets

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js

I am using sailsjs version 0.10.5 . In my sails js application when I run `sails lift --prod` all css files and js files are concatenate and saved in .tmp/public/min folder as production.min.css and production.min.js. But when I view the page source of my application I can see the relevant js files and css files seperately without concatenation. Am I missing something here ? Any kind of help would be appreciated. Following is my prod.js file inside tasks/register folder.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('prod', [
        'compileAssets',
        'concat',
        'uglify',
        'cssmin',
        'sails-linker:prodJs',
        'sails-linker:prodStyles',
        'sails-linker:devTpl',
        'sails-linker:prodJsJade',
        'sails-linker:prodStylesJade',
        'sails-linker:devTplJade'
    ]);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.9/assets.md

Follow this link, Its explaining all about **asset injection** in sails js